# drill down UITableView using storyboard in iOS program

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to develop an iOS app that has drill down UITable View. I got a drill down table view tutorial, but the number of UITableViews is static. What I need is a dynamic one. My requirement is simple. I need to access an FTP Server and get the directory hierarchy (I guess I need to store it in NSDictionary or in an xml file) and display the content in the UITableView. If it is a text file, I need to display it in some view, otherwise I need to display the selected folder's content in the same UITableView, and it goes on till the bottom of the directory hierarchy.

I need to use the storyboard.

Comment: Im sure I've answered a duplicate of this but I can't find it! You can make a segue from a view controller to itself which allows you to nest as often as you like.

Comment: I got the solution from this link http://jleeiii.blogspot.sg/2012/05/uistoryboard-power-drill-batteries.html. This is what exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Found it - possible duplicate of [UI Elements and IBOutlet Variables in Storyboard when instantiated recursively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488556/ui-elements-and-iboutlet-variables-in-storyboard-when-instantiated-recursively) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10767573/programming-uiviewcontrollers-cycles-with-ios-and-storyboard/10767832#10767832

Comment: Thanks jrturton. That as well helps. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make a something very similar to what your talking about in a previous application I worked on.

In that I created table views inside of table view cells with a button at the top to expand and collapse the view using the cell height.

This worked pretty well but since then I've found the best way to simply programmatically add ui elements to either your table view cells or view.

In both cases I created a management system using parent child architecture to hold your information.

I hope this puts you in the right direction :)

Comment: Hi Richard, The problem is I won't know the number of Tables views that I require so I need it at run time.

Comment: Yea thats the beauty of table view cells. They get built in runtime. So you don't actually build the ones you see until their in view.